# Como puedo poner esto fuera de OnCreate en Android

Tags: android-studio, variables-globales

Estoy utilizando variables globales en la siguiente clase:

```
public class VariablesOpcion_HassMovil extends Application {

private String cuenta=null;

public String getCuenta(){
    return this.cuenta;
}

public void setCuenta(String Cuenta){
    this.cuenta=Cuenta;


   }

}
```

y en `Oncreate` tengo lo siguiente:

```
VariablesOpcion_HassMovil variables = (VariablesOpcion_HassMovil) getApplication();
    variables.setCuenta("encargado");
```

Mi problema es que `variable` lo necesito usar no solo en `OnCreate` y lo he intendado poner fuera para usarlo en cualquier lado del activity pero me marca error, ¿como podria hacerlo?

Comment: En `onCreate` de que clase? `onCreate` en  `VariablesOpcion_HassMovil`?

Comment: `public class Cortes_Listado extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse {`
Es un activity

Comment: Y el error que te marca, eso es en la IDE (y que dice) o es una excepción cuando corres la app?

Answer (score 0):

Es una clase no estática por lo tanto puedes realizar lo siguiente, defines una variable tipo `VariablesOpcion_HassMovil` a nivel de clase:

```
  private  VariablesOpcion_HassMovil variables;
```

Antes de utilizar la variable tienes que instanciarla  y asinar el valor:

```
 variables = new VariablesOpcion_HassMovil();
 variables.setCuenta("encargado");
```

con esto puedes obtener el valor que asignaste en cualquier parte de tu clase:

```
Log.i("VariablesOpcion_HassMovil", variables.getCuenta());
```

---

Esto no tiene sentido, creas una variable tipo `VariablesOpcion_HassMovil`  que es igual a al aplicación pero esta aplicación la casteas como `VariablesOpcion_HassMovil`? recuerda que VariablesOpcion_HassMovil extiende de `Application`.

```
VariablesOpcion_HassMovil variables = (VariablesOpcion_HassMovil) getApplication();
```